# Razor view returns empty when using Authorize attrib on controller

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, iis-10

I am getting an empty page and this exception (configure web.config to write log) from Login.cshtml when trying to setup authentication in a asp.net core 2 project hosted on iis 10.

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider[48]
      An error occurred while reading the key ring.
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys\key-a269af3e-9a68-43f4-95c0-0dbebb957639.xml' is denied.
   at System.IO.FileStream.OpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileA...
```

Web.config to write to log:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
      <!--on iis 10-->
      <aspNetCore
        processPath="dotnet"
        arguments=".\GotoLink.Web.dll"
        stdoutLogEnabled="true"
        stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

How do I get authentication to work?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be easily fixed:

See "Data protection"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis?tabs=aspnetcore2x#data-protection

I selected option 2